# Extract text from HTML iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text and Titaniumfier - https://www.npmjs.com/package/titaniumifier on Ti SDK 6.0.2 to extract text from a HTML but it stopped to work on Titanium SDK 6.3.0.GA. I think there's something wrong on how Titaniumfier exports it. Do you have an alternative for extracting text from HTML for Titanium? Maybe something from its SDK or some pure Javascript function.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error it's showing in Ti 6.3.0 ?

Comment: The message says:
V8Exception: Exception occurred at /html-to-text/html-to-text.js:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token